# Distinct Rows From Vb.Net DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, group-by

I have a scenario, in which I have to apply distinct filter onto `DataTable` and find the rows only which are distinct,
I am using `dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, Columns)` this statement but no effect.

Here is my chunk of code..

```
Try
        Dim dTable As New DataTable()
        dTable.Columns.Add("AutoID")
        dTable.Columns.Add("AnotherID")
        dTable.Columns.Add("CitY")
        Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4
            row = dTable.NewRow()
            row("AutoID") = i + 1
            row("AnotherID") = i + 10
            row("City") = "Vetican"
            dTable.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        dTable.Rows.Add(6, "11", "Oslo")
        dTable.Rows.Add(7, "12", "Toronto")

        Dim TobeDistinct As String() = {"AnotherID"}
        Dim dtDistinct As DataTable = GetDistinctRecords(dTable, TobeDistinct)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

and the method ..

```
Public Shared Function GetDistinctRecords(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal Columns As String()) As DataTable
    Dim dtURecords As New DataTable()
    dtURecords = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, Columns)
    Return dtURecords
End Function
```

Here is the screen shot , which I want..
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which rows do you want to keep and which rows should be removed? If you just want to keep one row per `AnotherID` it seems to be arbitrary to keep `Vetican` instead of `Oslo`. Maybe you want to concat both as in `Vetican, Oslo`.

I would use `Linq` instead:

```
Dim resultTable = dTable.Clone() ' empty table same columns
Dim idGroups = dTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("AnotherID"))
For Each grp In idGroups
    Dim r As DataRow = resultTable.Rows.Add()
    r.SetField("AutoID", grp.First().Field(Of String)("AutoID"))
    r.SetField("AnotherID", grp.Key)
    Dim cities = From row In grp Select row.Field(Of String)("City")
    r.SetField("City", String.Join(", ", cities))
Next
```

Comment: It Says `Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.`

Comment: I want to keep all distinct Rows on the bases of `AnotherID` column

Comment: @DareDevil: then you're using .NET 3.5, so Visual Studio 2008. You can use `r.SetField("City", String.Join(", ", cities.ToArray()))`. I know, but which row do you want to keep if you have three duplicates according to the `AnotherID`-column? My approach above concats all cities with comma.

Comment: Can I use like this `Dim drows() As DataRow = dTable.Select("GROUP BY AnotherID Having COUNT(AnotherID) > 1 ")`